# Continues displaying [MC] Invalidating cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, caching

After running application observer that there is continues displaying `[MC] Invalidating cache` message in console.

In order to remove I have Edit Scheme added `"Environment Variables"` added `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` Set value `disable`

How to stop continues display `[MC] Invalidating cache` without `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` Set value `disable`